# Adding the policy to the role which is automatically generated

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cdk

I want to give the role additional policy
The role is made automatically,

My code is like this below

```
const aiAutoScalingGroup = new autoscaling.AutoScalingGroup(this, 'ai-asg', {
  vpc,
  instanceType: new ec2.InstanceType('g4dn.xlarge'),
 
  machineImage: ec2.MachineImage.genericLinux({
    "ap-northeast-1":"ami-023ec1c000b5029be"
  }),

  minCapacity:0,
  maxCapacity:1,

  vpcSubnets: {subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_WITH_EGRESS }
});
const policyStatement = new iam.PolicyStatement({
  actions: ['cloudwatch:PutMetricData'],
  resources: ['*']
}); 


role = aiAutoScalingGroup.role.node.defaultChild as iam.CfnRole;
role.addToPolicy(policyStatement);//The comes error. CfnRole has no addToPolicy
```

How can I give the additional policy to the role automatically generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to pass a custom role to the autoscaling group's construct mate:

```
const role = new iam.Role(this, 'MyRole', {
     assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal('ec2.amazonaws.com')
});

const aiAutoScalingGroup = new autoscaling.AutoScalingGroup(this, 'ai-asg', {
  vpc,
  instanceType: new ec2.InstanceType('g4dn.xlarge'),
  role,
  machineImage: ec2.MachineImage.genericLinux({
    "ap-northeast-1":"ami-023ec1c000b5029be"
  }),

  minCapacity:0,
  maxCapacity:1,

  vpcSubnets: {subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_WITH_EGRESS }
});
```

Comment: thank you very much. I tried this method,but the roll has different policies from the one auomatically created, do i need to give the necessary policy for autoscalling group to my roll manually?

Comment: AH, I was wrong. it has the default ASG policy even I added my role.Problem solved thank you very much.